# Can I make my application run automatically when the computer Startup in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net-2010

In my application i want to know if I could in Visual Basic to make this application run automatically when the computer Startup.

I don't Have any code or ideas about this subject, So i need a sample example please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a registry entry for your program to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` or one of the other run-on-startup registry keys or filesystem locations.

Comment: Hi cjc343.
thanks, but i need to do this with a simple code, can you help me?